# How to change the color of the 3D Text Object provided by SceneKit via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

How can I chagne the color of the scnText object via IB or scenekit UI ? I attached a couple of 3D texts to my scenekit and now I was trying to change the default color of the text, which is white, to something else. Is it possible? If yes, will appreciate the any help.

[image]

Comment: let textGeometry = SCNText(string: "TestText", extrusionDepth: 2.0)
textGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue

Comment: How can I do it via scenekit UI and not via code?